# How to send parameter values to server using Socketchannel?

Tags: java, android, socketchannel

I'm using **SocketChannel** to send a file from the client to the server in my android application.

It's working without any issues. But I need to send a file name as well to the server. Is it possible to set a request parameter to Socketchannel like HttpPost?

I tried searching many forums but no luck. If anyone having in depth knowledge on SocketChannel please share the answer with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can . what have you tried? sending a parameter is simpler than sending a file.

Comment: I tried using setOption(). But value is coming as 'null' at the server side.

Comment: You have to send it as *data,* just like the file data.

Comment: the options set how the socket behaves, nothing is sent to the other end.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: thanks for your reply. Let me try some other logic.

Comment: 'Some other logic' such as sending the filename as data?